# Power Platform Pricing Plan vs Office 365 Business Plan

Tags: office365

I tried to find any information related to the Power Platform when using an Office 365 Business Plan or Premium, but did not find anything. So, I know you can use the consumption plans for individual services on Power Platform, such as Power Apps, Automate, etc. But, I noticed that my company's Office 365 plan gives me access to the Power Platform, including Power Apps, Automate, etc. So, if I get an Office 365 Business Plan or Premium, do I have access to Power Platform as well? Anyone knows about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I see this question was asked almost 2 years back so I'm assuming by now, you would know the answer to the question. If not, let me add on to the other answer, which already includes some relevant info.

To have the use rights for Power Apps + Power Automate with your Microsoft 365 plan, you should at least have Office 365 E1 license. Please note, as the original answer also states, this DOES NOT include premium connectors and other premium features.

For more info, refer to the attached image:

[Power Apps Use Rights with O365](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hB8R.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

following link will provide you the standard inclusion. Most of what's included is the standard features in o365 license. for Premium features I think you need to spend extra on license.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/pricing-billing-skus

But sometimes a tailored agreement may be in place, therefore always check with your vendor manager or procurement team the Microsoft account manager.

Please note that there are standalone plans as well and you can refer to those in the link above.